# C# mXparser DLL error

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I've been getting this error every time I try to run the executable file from the project.

[image: mXparser Error]

I'm using .NET framework 4.6 and have downloaded the 'bin only' files from the mXparser site.

Comment: Are you sure that mxparser.dll is in the directory where you are running the applcation from?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just install it via NuGet? You have everything automated and don't have to worry about the whole "dll" process.

You can can look it up using the manager OR add it with the following line of code:

```
Install-Package MathParser.org-mXparser -Version 4.1.1
```

In case you want to continue with the "manual method" make sure that the dll file is the same directory where you have the executable at. If you're building the app using Visual Studio this should be the "Debug" folder located in "bin".